# RでCSVファイルのとある列がなぜか分析できない

Tags: r, csv

１列目に日付，２列目から数百列ほど株価の各営業日の終値データを並べたエクセルファイルをCSV形式に直したファイルを使って，Rで統計分析を試みております．
各銘柄ごとのリターンを出し，二次計画法を用いてマーコビッツの最小分散を求める際，ある特定の列（１０３列目）が引っ掛かり，以下のようなエラーが出ます．

```
Error in solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec = bvec, meq = 2) : 
  constraints are inconsistent, no solution!
```

銘柄を増減させたりコピーペーストを試したり，データの欠損を確認したり試行錯誤をしましたが，１０３列目のデータ配列がどうしても引っかかります．
何度確認しても見かけ上形式はほかの列と同様で，ダブりも見当たりません．

何か原因がお分かりになる方，どうか教えていただけませんでしょうか．

Comment: これはエラーメッセージの通りなのではないでしょうか。つまり、`Dual method of Goldfarb and Idnani` における制約条件(`Amat^T bvec >= bvec^T`)に引っかかったので解がない、という事です。

Comment: 銘柄のリターン平均が最大最小のものそれぞれを上限下限としてウェイトをかけ最小分散を求めているので，解がないとは考えにくいのです
制約も一般的なものと同様，ウェイトの合計が１，ウェイトとリターンをかけたものがポートフォリオのリターン，すべてのウェイトが０以上となる（空売りを認めない）です．

Comment: RStudioから代えてR64bitで回したところ，同様のエラーは出ましたが，最小分散集合はプロットされました（RStudioではエラーの後停止）．ただ，一点ウェイトの合計が０になったりいろいろおかしなところはあります．